# How do I use jbpm demo in a professional environment?

Tags: java, wildfly, jbpm, kie

I have installed http://download.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-6.4.0.Final-installer-full.zip found here http://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html and this is a self contained environment with ant and commands like: "ant install.demo". You end up with a nice environment for learning the kie workbench.

This is great for learning, but I really want to take it to the next step which is to have a single wildfly server with ear/war file(s). I can't seem to find instructions or advice on how to do this.

I cannot imagine having a VM where I have to remote desktop in and issue an "ant install.demo" or restart.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the answer is - not much. Unfortunately, the jBPM suite is very not-user-friendly when it comes to using it within your own standalone application.

The demo installer basically does install a Wildfly instance that runs the respective WARs, so in a sense, it does exactly what you want. However, the big problem is customizing the solution. The installer comes with prepackaged WARs and if you want to customize some solutions (for example, override the security provider), you have to recompile and repackage the relevant code from source.

What I would recommend is instead of using the full jBPM suite, use the requisite components. You can use the jBPM core engine as a standalone library, without really deploying it as a separate WAR.

If you want specific hints, please feel free to ask. Also, if you want to recompile the jBPM components under Windows, get ready for a lot of hurt (and using custom Maven GWT builders).

Comment: Thanks Piotr. Can you explain your thoughts on this: "You can use the jBPM core engine as a standalone library".  I'm not sure if you mean that we can remove everything but wildfly or something else. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, what he meant is that you do not have to use the workbench if you do not need it. You can build your own web application based on jBPM engine which will be used just as a library. However, in this case you will have to provide all GUI parts of the application yourself.

Comment: In our case we have the engine as part of our platform. What I mean by that, is the engine that executes the business work flows. The tool used to build the workflows is currently a separate entity. We have a single Drools workbench server built via a war file with wildfly. I was trying to figure out if the jBPM suite was what I "should" be using. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Note that there is another (and recommended) solution called **KIE Server**. Basically, it is a lightweight WAR which contains jBPM, Drools and OptaPlanner engines and exposes their functionality through REST and JMS interfaces. Unfortunately, it is not mentioned in the jBPM documentation at all (only in the [Drools](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/pt06.html) or [BPM Suite](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html/User_Guide/chap-The_Realtime_Decision_Server.html) documentation).

Answer (score 1):

jBPM installer is really just for demo purposes. If you want to use it in production, you should get [JBoss BPM Suite](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite/). If you do not want to pay, it is much harder to get something useful unless you build the whole system from the source code. But you can still find WAR files optimized for different containers on JBoss Nexus. You can download [KIE Workbench](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~kie-wb-distribution-wars) or [KIE Server](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~kie-server) in the latest stable version **6.4.0.Final**.