# JBPM Workflow deployment

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I am very new to JBPM and KieWorkbench ,infact from .net background.

I've installed JBPM  6 on my machine and have developed some guided rules and workflows using KieWorkbench.
On local I can easily create,run and Test workflows and Rules, because as I do ant start.demo all setup is done.

Moving forward now I've to deploy this on production environment and share the source code with team members.
Limitation is I cannot use Git.

Now I've 2 questions :-
1.How to deploy this on production?
2.How can I share code/project with my teammates.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to deploy in production? Do you want to find a way how to deploy KIE Workbench in production? Or do you already have it running and you just want to deploy your processes there?

Comment: Deploy KIE Workbench on production.

Comment: I've developed Rules and workflows on my local, I've to deploy it on production. I don't know how it will be like to deploy on Production. Do I need to have a Wildfly server on production if yes then how I'll be able to deploy my current projects and rules to that server. Also I need to share code how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question about using KIE Workbench in production environment. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39010458/3047439). If you do not need GUI, I would recommend to use KIE Server for process execution. Unfortunately, it is not described in jBPM documentation but you can find it in the [Drools](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e23764) one.

When it comes to sharing projects created in KIE Workbench, you can do one of these two things:

- Clone a Git repository from KIE Workbench. It should be available on address `git://localhost:9418/repository_name`.
- Deploy a project in KIE Workbench and find the artifact with your process and rule definitions in your `~/.m2/repository`.

It may also be a good idea to have your development version of KIE Workbench deployed somewhere where others can access it and see your process definitions directly in this application.

Comment: For the first part of your answer I might require GUI, also I checked my wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments folder it is containing 4 files namely :-1. jbpm-console.war,2.jbpm-console.war.deployed,kie-server.war and 4. kie-server.war.deployed. So as per deployment steps mentioned in Drools link if I install jbpm-console also, will I be able to get the GUI?

Comment: jBPM Console is basically a subset of KIE Workbench and both of them have GUI. You can see the difference in a nice diagram [here](http://blog.athico.com/2013/10/hi-all-this-is-follow-up-post-from-my.html). In case you want to use one of them, you do not really need to deploy KIE Server since they have their own execution engines. This is only required in the upcoming jBPM 7 where the engines have been removed from KIE Workbench and now it makes remote calls to KIE Server.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly I need to do following steps :-
1. Download and install Wildfly server.
2. Add users to this server
3. Download the kie-wb-distribution-wars 
4. Deploy the war file from the admin console.

Doing so I'll be having a production environment with GUI.
Also if required I can configure the server to have its users authenticated and authorized from DB.

@livthomas please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/bpm/jbpm/get-started-with-jbpm-kie-and-drools-workbench-part-1/

Comment: Yes, you are basically right. I have not read that article but in addition to the steps you have described, you will need to run Wildfly server with `standalone-full.xml` configuration, you will probably want to use some other DB than the default H2, and you can also deploy WAR file just by putting it inside `standalone/deployments` folder.

Comment: Please note that you can only download community builds of KIE Workbench. If you really want to use it in your company in production environment, I would recommend to buy [JBoss BPM Suite](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite/) which is productized version of jBPM, Drools, and other projects with full support from Red Hat. In comparison with community Final version, the GA version of the product is much more stable and it receives a lot of bugfix updates even after that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You do not really need Git to get your process definitions from KIE Workbench as I mentioned in my answer above.